# C++ Passing a Dynamically Created Array with Pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Hoping for a little C++ assistance - I'm very new to the topic. I'm attempting to dynamically create an array based on user input with a pointer, then pass the array to a function. But the pointer (and thus array) pass feels a little wrong because there is no dereferencing that occurs.

During/after passing, do we just treat the pointer as if it were any normally declared-and-passed array, without the need to dereference (*) anything? Or am I applying this incorrectly?

Pseudocode follows:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void arrayFunc(int [], int);    // << Note no indication of pointer pass

int main()
{
    int *arrayPtr = 0; // Array pointer
    int arrayElem = 0; // Number of elements in array

    cout << "\nPlease enter the number of elements: ";
    cin >> arrayElem;

    arrayPtr = new int[arrayElem]; // Dynamically create the new array
    arrayFunc(arrayPtr, arrayElem); // << Note no dereferencing or other indication of pointer

    return 0;
}

void arrayFunc(int array[], int arrayElem)  // << Same here - now it's just a plain old array
{
    // All the functiony-bits go here, referencing array without the need to dereference
}
```

[EDIT] While the above code works, the following includes the fixes determined in the discussion below:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void arrayFunc(int*, int);  // Changed to pointer pass instead of []

int main()
{
    int *arrayPtr = 0; // Array pointer
    int arrayElem = 0; // Number of elements in array

    cout << "\nPlease enter the number of elements: ";
    cin >> arrayElem;

    arrayPtr = new int[arrayElem]; // Dynamically create the new array
    arrayFunc(arrayPtr, arrayElem);

    return 0;
}

void arrayFunc(int* array, int arrayElem)   // Passing a pointer now instead of []
{
    // All the functiony-bits go here, referencing array without the need to dereference
}
```

Comment: Your pointer is a pointer to the first element of the array. Dereferencing it wouldn't allow you to pass in "the whole array".

Comment: Ahh, so, does `arrayPtr` just work like any normal array after the `new int[arrayElem]` statement?

Comment: It works the same way as if you had a pointer to the first element of a normal array (e.g., `int arr[10]; int *ptr = arr;`). It will work like an array for the most part, but not always (e.g., `sizeof(arr)` vs. `sizeof(arrayPtr)`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the pointer in your function, because it describes the situation accurately i.e. you are passing a dynamically allocated memory. `arrayPtr` is essentially a pointer to the first element of the array. As a result, you do not need to worry about dereferencing it.

Change the function signature to:

```
void arrayFunc(int*, int);
```

Comment: Ah interesting - so the prototype should indicate it's passing a pointer?

What about the function header `void arrayFunc(int array[], int arrayElem) { ... }`? Should this be changed to `void arrayFunc(int* array[], int arrayElem) { ... }`?

Comment: You are passing a pointer, not an array. So, the function header should look like `arrayFunc(int* array, int arrayElem) { ... }`

Comment: Perfect - thank you!

So, just to confirm, when we point to an array element there's no need to dereference (`myIntArrayPtr[0] = 1;`), but when we point to a non-array, such as an integer, we'd need to dereference (`*myIntPtr = 1;`)?

Comment: @WyattMiller when you use the square brackets [  ], you are dereferencing.

Comment: Aha! I didn't realize. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt is correct. You are passing the array pointer by value. You can then dereference it as normal within `arrayFunc`

Answer (score 1):

C is designed to pretend a pointer and an array are the mostly same thing.  Lots of simple uses are easier because of that.  But the concept gets much more confusing when you think about a pointer to an array.  It feels like it shouldn't be the same thing as a pointer to the first element of that array, but in the common methods for allocating memory and using pointers, a pointer to an array really is just a pointer to the first element of the array.

I find it best to think of "pointer to first element of array of" as the **normal** meaning of * in C.  The special case of pointing to a scalar object is effectively treating the scalar as the first (and only) element of an array of length 1.